# How do I set current Unix time in milliseconds?

Tags: date, coreutils

## Possible Solution

```
date --set="2011-12-07 01:20:15.962"  && date --rfc-3339=ns
```

## Original Question

I can get the date with milliseconds like so:

```
date +"%S.%N"
date --rfc-3339=ns
```

According to `man date` I would expect to be able to set it like so:

```
date --set=%s.%N +`date +"%S.%N"`
date --set="%s.%N" "+1323217126.085882000"
```

According to [my googling](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-set-date-time-from-linux-command-prompt/) I would expect to be able to set the date like so (the inverse of the above):

```
date +%s.%N -s `date +"%S.%N"`
date +"%s.%N" -s "1323217126.085882000"
```

Neither work. Can someone clue me in on the issue?

P.S. No, I don't need nanosecond resolution. Yes, I know bash execution takes milliseconds. What I really need is sub-second resolution, 10ths of a second would be good enough.

Comment: Why are you manually setting the time and not using something like ntp?

Comment: **You're Doing It Wrong™**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a solution (**Linux, NOT Unix**):

```
date --set="2011-12-07 01:20:15.962"  && date --rfc-3339=ns
```

Note the delay:

```
CURTIME=`date --rfc-3339=ns`
date --set="${CURTIME}"    
NEWTIME=`date --rfc-3339=ns`
echo ${CURTIME}
echo ${NEWTIME}

2011-12-07 01:48:54.687216122+00:00
2011-12-07 01:48:54.720541318+00:00
```

As you'll notice, **whole milliseconds of delay** are introduced. This is due to the time it takes to initialize memory for and load the `date` binary. This is true for all shells and the `exec` of insert-higher-level-language-here

However, if you just need sub-second resolution in the range of 10ths of a second, this will good enough in many cases.

Comment: And if you're (like me) toying around and feel `CURTIME` is outdated too much use `hwclock -s` to update sys time from hardware time (and don't use `hwclock -w` which will set hardware clock to sys time) ^^

Answer (score 2):

If your goal is to set time in with sub-second intervals, then date seems like the wrong command if I am reading the source correctly.

Assuming you are using the [coreutils](http://www.gnu.org/s/coreutils/) version of date, then it appears to me that `when.tv_nsec = 0` line is setting nanosecond portion of the `when` variable which is a timespec structure to zero.  Even if you could convince date to accept a more accurate value, it looks to me like it would be pointless.

```
  # time.h
  struct timespec
  {
    __time_t tv_sec;        /* Seconds.  */
    long int tv_nsec;       /* Nanoseconds.  */
  };

  # date.c

  struct timespec when;

  # ...

              valid_date = posixtime (&when.tv_sec,
                                      datestr,
                                      (PDS_TRAILING_YEAR
                                       | PDS_CENTURY | PDS_SECONDS));
              when.tv_nsec = 0; /* FIXME: posixtime should set this.  */
  # ...

          /* Set the system clock to the specified date, then regardless of
             the success of that operation, format and print that date.  */
          if (settime (&when) != 0)
            {
              error (0, errno, _("cannot set date"));
              ok = false;
            }
```

Comment: The version that ships with Ubuntu seems to work. See my updated post and solution.

Answer (score 1):

There is a better method that doesn't require converting the timestamp to a human-readable date format as in the accepted answer. You were extremely close with your original suggestion:

```
date +"%s.%N" -s "1323217126.085882000"
```

When giving timestamps, you need to prefix with an '@' like so and not quote them:

```
date +"%s.%N" -s @1323217126.085882000
```

This will now correctly set the current Linux time in seconds with millisecond accuracy.